# updating values to server in AG-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-validation

Here I'm Using **.net Core in Server Side  and plain vanilla JavaScript for UI**

AG grid is getting data from the SQL view thru ASP.net Core application.
in the Grid all the cells are editable. **now i want to have one button on top of the Grid. if the user clicks that button only changed data needs to save in DB.** is there any option to get oly dirt values or pls advice me how to achieve the above use-case.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there isn't such a complex solution implemented in ag-grid out of a box. But you can do it yourself with help of the events `cellValueChange` and/or `rowValueChange` (only if you are using `editType = 'fullRow'`).

I suggest to use the scenario `editType = 'fullRow'`. So whenever the `rowValueChange` fires, store the new data of that row in some data array (of course, if a user edits the same row the second time, you need to overwrite the previous stored row value). And when the button is pressed, you pushed to the server only data of that changed rows you've collected.